# Hibernate Mapping: coalesce two columns

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I would like to know if there is a way in hibernate to map one property in my application to the nonnull column or coalesce of the two columns in the table I am mapping.

For example, MyTable contains columns TypeA and TypeB. There is a constraint on the table where one of these two columns has to be non-null. I want to map my hibernate property called MyType to the nonnull column. The reason for this is that I would like to manage this at the hibernate level rather than add checks throughout my application to decide whether I want to use TypeA or TypeB as MyType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

**1. Using Custom Property**

```
@Entity
public class MyTable {
    @Column
    private String typeA;

    @Column
    private String typeB;

    public getType() {
        return (null == typeA) ? typeB : typeA;
    }

    //typeA, typeB getter setters
}
```

And then you can use `type` (getType) through out your application to get typeA or typeB depending on null criteria

**2. Using `@Formula` or `<formula>`**
Or you can use @Formula ([5.1.4.1.5. Formula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e6481)) to define a new derived column based on values of typeA and typeB:

```
@Entity
public class MyTable {
    @Column
    private String typeA;

    @Column
    private String typeB;


    @Formula(case typeA when null then typeB else typeA) //Oracle only
    private String type;
}
```

The second approach is database dependent. So use it with caution.